# How to retrieve data from one table based on the calculation of another two table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

Suppose I have Three model named as `Customer ,Invoice` and `Payment`.
Invoice  and Payment model looks like

`id , customer_id, amount`

I want to get only  those customer whose 
    `Invoice.sum(amount)>Payment.sum(amount)`  with these amount difference

I am currently retrieve like

```
$customers=Customer::get();
foreach($customers as $customer)
{  
  $pay=Payment::where('customer_id',$customer->id)->sum('amount');
  $due=Invoice::where('customer_id',$customer->id)->sum('amount');
  if($due>$pay){
   // showing this customers 
   }
}
```

Is there any better way with eloquent join?
How Can I get In laravel eloquent ?

Comment: Could you show us the columns of the tables and their relationships?

Comment: @Miggy customer_id is foreign key in both Payment and Invoice model which is the primary key in Customer model

Comment: @Miggy Both Invoice and Payment model column are :                                   
                id , customer_id, amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set any relationship in the Model? A better eloquent query will look like this. You might need to adjust a bit

```
Customer::join('payment','customer.id','=','payment.customer_id')
          ->join('invoice','customer.id','=','invoice.customer_id')
          ->select(array('customer.*'),DB::raw("SUM(payment.amount) as payment_sum,SUM(invoice.amount) as invoice_sum"))
          //->where('customer_id',$customer->id)
          ->groupBy('customer.id')  //replace with anything that make sense for you.
          ->havingRaw('invoice_sum > payment_sum')
          ->get();
```

Comment: kean  In mysql raw query it's working fine just removing where('customer_id',$customer->id) clause but in larave it not working   . It shows Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Comment: i think you need to add a groupby('column') before using the havingRaw() see if it works

Comment: KEAN Yes it work if I add groupBy('customers.id') but it shows me customers.name not in group by . How can I solve it . note that I have also set 'strict' => false, in database.php

Comment: @kean still there is an error 1052 Column 'customer_id' in group statement is ambiguous

Comment: If I use 'customer.id'  instead of 'customer.*' it work fine . But I also need the customer table data

Comment: You need to specify which table's customer id you're using as mentioned ambiguous. The groupby i gave was just a sample input. To be exact try customer.id...the select('customer. *') should get all column from customer table 

Comment: after moving the select statement before the join  also same problem

Comment: Oh i see the mistake i've done. Try checkout the updated answer again

Comment: still same problems

Comment: Uhm..Which problem exactly. The customer column not showing up or groupby problem.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'possementrod.customers.name' isn't in GROUP BY

Comment: possementrod.customers.name? i think just play around with the groupny()..Maybe ' groupBy('customer.id','payment.cusomter_id',invoice.customer_id'')'

Comment: possementrod is database name

Comment: I have just little bit change Model name and column for simplicity  .     Actual error message is     (2/2) QueryException

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'possementrod.customers.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select customers.*,SUM(customer_payments.amount) as payment_sum,SUM(invoices.total_price) as invoice_sum from `customers` inner join `customer_payments` on `customers`.`id` = `customer_payments`.`customer_id` inner join `invoices` on `customers`.`id` = `invoices`.`customer_id` group by `customers`.`id` having invoice_sum > payment_sum)

Comment: I have not include I have just copy and past your code and change model name and column name . but error message show me like this

Comment: If i past this query showing this error message in mysql query window it work absolutely fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this

First, define the relationship in your `Customer` Model

```
public function payments()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Payment::class); //based on your logic or structure
}

public function invoices()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Invoice::class); //based on your logic or structure
}
```

```
Customer::with(['payments' => function($query) {
               $query->sum('amount');
         }])
        ->get();
```

or

```
$customers=Customer::with('payments','invoices')->get();
foreach($customers as $customer)
{  
  $pay = $customer->payments()->sum('amount');
  $due = $customer->invoices()->sum('amount');

   //other logic
}
```